# System.Reflection.TargetOfInvocation exception when loading new List

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an `MvxListView` that binds to a Collection. When I first navigate to the ViewModel I load data from the server and set the List. The view loads great.

I have then set an `OnScroll` listener to the `ListView` so that I can load the next page when the user scrolls to the bottom. I kick off the command to get the "next page" of results using a command like the following :

```
this.ViewModel.ShowNextPageCommand.Execute(null);
```

The Command ultimately calls a method that uses some state in the ViewModel to get the          next page, all of that is working fine but when I actually go to update the Property that the ListView is bound to, I get the following error --

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an      invocation. ---> Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Exception of type     'Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException' was thrown.
06-21 14:58:27.969 E/mono    (28485):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00023] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/0cc7ae3b/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:604 
06-21 14:58:27.969 E/mono    (28485):   at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00053] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/0cc7ae3b/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.cs:293
```

The Property looks like the following :

```
private ICollection<Part> parts;
public ICollection<Part> Parts
{
    get { return parts; }
    set
    {
        this.parts = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=>Parts);

    }
}
```

and the code that updates the property looks like the following :

```
private void HandlePartResults(PartsResults results)
{
    if (this.Results == null)
    {
        this.Results = results;
        this.Parts = results.Parts;
    }
    else
    {

        this.Results.Links.Clear();
        this.Results.Links.AddRange(results.Links);
        foreach (var part in results.Parts)
        {
            this.Results.Parts.Add(part);
        }
       Mvx.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic,Results.Parts.Count.ToString());
        this.Parts = Results.Parts;
    }
    this.IsLoading = false;
}
```

My Layout looks like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.x3wire.mobile.android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility IsLoading,Converter=Visibility" />
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/PartResultsList"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/partslistitem"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Parts; ItemClick ShowDetailCommand" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I've tried to use an observable collection as well but I get the same exception. Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing obvious - keep debugging... Maybe try to get more info about what the inner exception is? Maybe try it in a separate simple test app with dummy data - can you get it working there?

Comment: @Stuart Thanks, I'll try to dig a bit deeper... My Android debugger is busted so I'm going to try re-installing Xamarin. I've been making due with console logs :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figure out what the issue was (it wasn't an MVVMcross problem at all). Once I got my debugger fixed, it was apparent there was some threading issues (and that the OnScroll Listener was getting fired more than it needed to be).

Long story short, make sure you don't have multiple threads trying to modify a collection at the same time when it is bound to a view and make sure you don't try to debug such issues via console.writes :D